# How to find package name for particular class of java from terminal

Tags: java, gnome-terminal

for Example, lets say i want to use ArrayList so I've to use

> `import java.util.ArrayList;`

in my java source. But in case i forgot that ArrayList is included in `java.util` package.
so ***how do i find*** a **package name of ArrayList class** ?

1. assuming i don't have internet
2. assuming i don't want to browse source

Comment: You can't even install the documentation?

Comment: @muru no i am just looking at terminal commands. I've all the doccs and source. just describing scenario at my college.

Comment: If you can install the docs, you can browse them. They're all HTML files in `/usr/share/doc/openjdk*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you use for development, but I'm using [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and I never have to care about any import statement. I just start to type `ArrL` and IDEA will take care of the rest. It will suggest `ArrayList<E>` for autocompletion and fix the import statement instantly. It just knows what you want to do and you can concentrate on development and not on remembering package names:

[image]

#### Edit:

An easy way to do it in the command-line is to search the `src.zip` file which comes with the SDK. So if you try to find `ArrayList` then you can do

```
7z l src.zip | grep ArrayList
```

and you get

```
2013-03-26 21:10:27 ..... 42659 8916 java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.java
2013-03-26 21:10:27 ..... 21547 5814 java/util/ArrayList.java
```

where you can see the package structure because it is similar to the sub-folders. I'm sure there are corner-cases where this doesn't work, but you can at least try.

Comment: Yes... Ide works fine... But i am talking about  -command line

Comment: @RohitKaradkar See my edit.

Comment: Yes that's something useful  for now

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `$JAVA_HOME` is set properly.

```
$ find $JAVA_HOME -name *.jar -print | xargs -n1 jar -tf | grep "ArrayList.class"
com/sun/istack/internal/FinalArrayList.class
com/sun/xml/internal/messaging/saaj/util/FinalArrayList.class
com/sun/xml/internal/org/jvnet/mimepull/FinalArrayList.class
sun/swing/BakedArrayList.class
sun/awt/util/IdentityArrayList.class
java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.class
java/util/Arrays$ArrayList.class
java/util/ArrayList.class
com/sun/javafx/UnmodifiableArrayList.class
org/eclipse/equinox/internal/p2/core/helpers/CollectionUtils$UnmodifiableArrayList.class
```

Little helper function, still assuming `JAVA_HOME` is set and set properly

```
function jfind () 
{ 
    if [[ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]]; then
        echo "Please set JAVA_HOME variable";
    else
        find $JAVA_HOME -name *.jar -print | xargs -n1 jar -tf | grep "$@";
    fi
}
```

**More common solution**

You can substitute `JAVA_HOME` by any path where desirable jars are located. For example your project path:

```
$ find some_folder_with_jars -name *.jar -print | xargs -n1 jar -tf | grep "Awesome.class"
```

**Sources**

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658026/how-to-get-list-of-all-classes-coming-with-particular-jdk-from-cli) answer